# Book's proof of:- Norm $N\alpha=1$ iff $\alpha$ is a unit

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As given in the book by Pollard, Diamond, on Algebraic Numbers, there are proofs for Norm, as shown below in pg. 7,8 of the book.
[image]

The issue is part(iii) proof, where the author states that "$\alpha\beta = 1$
for some $\beta$."

I am unclear about how $\beta = 1$, as it is shown in the next line : "$N(\alpha\beta) = N1 = 1$", which should have exploited (according to me) the assumption of choice of $\beta = 1$, & hence: $N(\alpha\beta)= N\alpha N\beta = 1$.

Comment: Why do you suppose that $\beta=1$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I have no other choice, if assume for the 'if' case $\alpha$ is a unit. Not a fraction, not even $-1$, not any other integer for value of $\beta$.

Comment: You are saying that you have no other choice than to assume that the inverse of every unit is $1$....

Comment: Yes, although never thought like in terms of the language of 'the inverse of every unit is 1', but semantics is the same.

Comment: Inverse of 1 is 1, of -1 is -1, of i is -i, and of -i is i. These are all the Gaussian integer units.

Comment: @user8734617 But, here $\alpha$ is unit, so the meaning of unit (as per you) can be unit in imaginary or real plane, i.e. $i, -i$, and similarly $alpha$ can be $-1$, apart form the usual $1$. So, if $\alpha =\pm i, \beta = \mp i$, or if $ \alpha = \pm 1, \beta = \pm 1$.

Comment: Yes, was in haste and edited my earlier comment.

Comment: This is now correct, except these are not just "as per me"; these are all the units (=invertible with respect to multiplication).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\beta=1$ is not assumed anywhere.

The author first assumes $\alpha $ is a unit (i.e. has a multiplicative inverse), thus $ \alpha\beta=1$ for some $\beta $.

Then the author uses (ii) (norm of the product is the product of the norms) to apply $N $ to this product and get $N (\alpha)N(\beta)=N(\alpha\beta)=N (1)=1$.

This means $N(\alpha)=1$ (and $N(\beta)=1$, for that matter).

**Note**: The units in the ring the author is talking about (Gaussian integers, or $\mathbb Z [i] $) are: $1, -1, i, -i $. Their inverses are, respectively, $1, -1,-i,i $. They all have norm 1, and no other Gaussian integer has norm 1. That is the essence of the author's claim.